# MySQL SUM does not work with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have these tables

[image: customers table]

[image: products table]

[image: purchases table]

[image: versions table]

When I execute this query

```
SELECT 
    products.name,
    versions.version, 
    purchases.`purchase date`, 
    SUM(purchases.`number of licenses`) 
FROM products,
    versions, 
    purchases 
WHERE 
    products.id = versions.`product id` 
    AND products.id = 1
GROUP BY
    products.name, 
    versions.version;
```

I get this result:

[image]

Where number of licences is the total sum of purchases in the table, when I expect only 20 (with product id = 1, that is rows 8, 10, 11) instead of 54.

Could someone help me with this, please?

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but try changing WHERE to HAVING, and move the HAVING clause after the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: He doesn't need the having clause, there he is not filtering on any aggregates. He does need to add the purchase date field to the GROUP BY clause, as it is in the SELECT list, along w/ an aggregate function, but is not in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: You do not have any join conditions between the VERSIONS and PURCHASES tables. This will create a cartesian product. Also, while it is not affecting your output, use the JOIN clause for join conditions, not the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause does not mention `purchases` so it's summing all purchase for every row.

You will be better off expressing the joins using modern `JOIN ... ON` syntax.  Since you haven't provided table definitions it's hard to specify what you should do.

The following is a rough guess to show you the syntax.  It will certainly not work as-is; you must tweak it for your situation.

```
SELECT 
    pr.name,
    v.version, 
    pu.`purchase date`, 
    SUM(pu.`number of licenses`) 
FROM products pr
    JOIN versions v on pr.id = v.`product id` 
    JOIN purchases pu 
       on pu.product_id=pr.product_id 
      and pu.product_version_id=v.version_id
GROUP BY
    pr.name, 
    v.version;
```

Comment: would you mind if I ask what does this error mean: `Unknown column 'products.name' in 'field list' ? I see it after executing you example, but `products.name` column is definitely present in the database.

Comment: Also I added examples of the tables, so may be you would be able to look on them

Comment: As I said, my example was merely for basic structure and not intended to be ready to execute.  I forgot to replace the select-list table names with the aliases I assigned. I've fixed the example.  It would be very beneficial to you to take some time to study the MySQL manual for a while to understand basic SQL syntax.